# <ul> tag going left?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I'm not getting what I wanted.
I made a div which will be in the right side of the website, with 200px width. Then I made a  to display links with a list. The problem is, any element inside that  is going slightly to left, as if there was a padding-right in it, but there isn't, and I have no idea where this is coming from.

```css
.nav-menu>ul {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-menu>ul>li {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  list-style: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-menu>ul>li>a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.lnr {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="pt-link active"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-home"></i></span>Home </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-user"></i></span>About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resume" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-license"></i></span>Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-briefcase"></i></span>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-book"></i></span>Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-envelope"></i></span>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks!

[Image of the result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ2v4.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this in your css:

```
body,html{
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-menu>ul {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-menu>ul>li {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  list-style: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-menu>ul>li>a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.lnr {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="pt-link active"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-home"></i></span>Home </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-user"></i></span>About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resume" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-license"></i></span>Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-briefcase"></i></span>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-book"></i></span>Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="pt-link"><span class="nav-menu-icon"><i class="lnr lnr-envelope"></i></span>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```